# Large title doesn't appear large

Tags: swift, navigation, storyboard

I have a scrollview containing a stack view that contains buttons that perform a segue to a table view controller.

When the title is large on the parent view controller with the scroll view and you tap a button the table view controller appears with a large title, but when doing the same after having scrolled down in the parent view controller (thus having a standard title) the table view controller appears with a standard title as well.

Is there a way to make it appear large at all times? Because it is not supposed to appear as a standard title.

When you go back it does fine.

Once you swipe somewhere in the table view controller it changes to a large title.

I'm using storyboard

---

Edit:

It appears these people were having similar issues but also haven't found a solution.

[Large title is initially collapsed after push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62627199/large-title-is-initially-collapsed-after-push)

[Large title collapses after a push segue](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/g2knmp/large_title_collapses_after_a_push_segue/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some messing around this seems like a glitch in Xcode (for me at least)

I've managed to fix it by adding

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

in

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
```

Hope this might be useful for other people in the future